# Can't access to the system after an update

Tags: grub2, system-installation, system, grubrescue, memtest

Last night I got security updates notifications on my laptop operating under Ubuntu 14.04 so when I procede I got error message telling me that I need some 25Mo of space ..
So as usual I made

```
apt-get -y purge linux-image-3.0.13.60
```

And etc .. but because I have from 60 to 69 versions I tried the following:

```
apt-get -y purge linux-image-3.0.13.6*
```

I thought that will purge any version until the 70th .
After he finished I installed the current update and I rebooted when he asked me to do  .
After the reboot I found this screen 
[image]

I waited for Memtest86 but nothing .. it started again in some kind of a loop ..
So when I pressed esc I found that 
[image]

The Ubuntu system is missed and when I choosed the second choice I foud that :
[image]

No I know that I did a stupid thing .. but please is there anyway to fix it ..

Answer (score 1):

Man, you have no kernel! You can either reinstall your OS, or you could download and create a Ubuntu live cd/usb, mount your root partition, chroot into your root partition and install a kernel, like this (from the live cd/usb):

`mount /dev/sdaX /mnt 
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc/
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys/
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev/
chroot /mnt
apt-get install -y linux-image`

Comment: Please see the  update

Comment: yeah, that's grub's command line, do `ls (hd0,1)/` and see if you have anything that says "linux"

Comment: No nothing, the above command return : `lost+found/ memtest86.bin memtest86+.elf grub/ memtest86+multiboot.bin`

Comment: Yeah, that means you have to reinstall, you're missing the most important part of your system: linux kernel!

Comment: Does that mean all my other files are gone

Comment: Well, it depends where you keep your files. I noticed you have two partitions. Do you dual boot with windows? In the case you aren't dual booting and your second partition is where your $HOME folder is and where you keep your files, your files will be safe, if your careful and don't format it.BUT, if you boot from a installation cd or usb and DON'T install, but open a terminal and type the command I've written above (as root), the problem should be fixed. If you think your files aren't worth the effort of using the terminal, you should reinstall.

Comment: BUT, if you boot from a installation cd or usb and DON'T install, but open a terminal and type the commands I've written above (as root), the problem should be fixed. If you think your files aren't worth the effort of using the terminal, you should reinstall.

Comment: Thank you very much I will test it and tell you the result

Comment: by the way, the X in `mount /dev/sdaX /mnt ` must be replaced with the number of your root partition, which based on the last photo, I think is 1, so it should be: `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt `